# Problem when reading elements created in javascript vanilla?

Tags: javascript, typescript

93/5000
Hi, I have a question about reading an element after creating it, I have the following example

```html
function createTemplate()
{
  return (`
          <div class="test1">
            <div class="test2">
              <tr>  
                <td class="addth"></td>
                <td class="sumth"></td>
              </tr>
            <div>
          </div>
          `);
}

function readTemplate()
{
  const read = document.querySelector('.sumth');
  console.log(read);
}

function btnRead()
{
  const insert = document.getElementById('content');
  insert.innerHTML = createTemplate();
  readTemplate();
}
```

My problem is that the first time I execute the button that calls the functions does not detect the "sumth" td that is the value that I need to work it, it detects me null then if I give it again to execute the button it detects me, but with the previous value that I had since I need it is that I capture that value at the moment since this value is dynamic and changes every time I execute. Please do not know what my error is or how to read a created component, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `tr` and `td` tags aren't in a `table`.  If you change the inner `div` tag to `table`, it'll work correctly.

```
function createTemplate()
{
  return (`
          <div class="test1">
            <table class="test2">
              <tr>  
                <td class="addth"></td>
                <td class="sumth"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          `);
}

function readTemplate()
{
  const read = document.querySelector('.sumth');
  console.log(read);
}

function btnRead()
{
  const insert = document.getElementById('content');
  insert.innerHTML = createTemplate();
  readTemplate();
}

btnRead()
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr>` needs to be in `<table>`, not `<div>`. The `<tr>` and `<td>` tags are being ignored because of this.

```js
function createTemplate() {
  return (`
          <div class="test1">
            <table class="test2">
              <tr>  
                <td class="addth">Cell 1</td>
                <td class="sumth">Cell 2</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          `);
}

function readTemplate() {
  const read = document.querySelector('.sumth');
  console.log(read);
}

function btnRead() {
  const insert = document.getElementById('content');
  insert.innerHTML = createTemplate();
  readTemplate();
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="btnRead()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but independent of placing it on a table does not recognize me at first, I have to make another click to identify the value and it always identifies me with the previous value that was not with the one I initially believe, you know how I can read the value at time to create it ??

Comment: You'll need to update the question to show how you're calling it, because it works fine in my code.